# SFC styles not being applied with testing-library

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm adding unit tests to our vue codebase and finding difficult to test an element visibility.

I render the component as usual and as recommended in the examples of the testing-library documentation, but the styles are not being applied to the DOM debugging (using screen.debug). Any clue on this?

Example:

Inside the component

```
<template>
  <span class="error-message>content here</span>
</template>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.error-message {
  display: none
}
```

In the (failing) test file:

```
render(Component);
expect(screen.getByText(/content here/i)).not.toBeVisible();
screen.debug();
```

The test fails because the element is visible. The debug prints the DOM as expected, except for the data-v-* classes that we usually see on browser inspect.

Comment: Does it work inside a `wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => { /* check here */ })`? Having to wait for the wrapper to update a changed data/prop is quite common.

Comment: It does not. The thing is that jest-dom won't do the assertion correctly based only on the class name, as the style is not being injected to the test environment. I changed my approach and tested the class name.

Comment: At least in theory, that's the right approach. When you're testing whether a particular class applies a particular style property to an element you're testing the DOM library itself, not your project. But from what you're saying, it sounds like your testing environment isn't parsing (or isn't getting all) styles.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the way the assertion was being made.
As i understand, the styles being applied through the class `error-message` is not going to be seen by the jest-dom because it wont be inject to the DOM's header in the test environment. So what i did was to assert the class names in the element.